# Javascript logic to sort object based on contains logic

Tags: javascript

I have an object as shown below:
`{abc: value1, ab: value2, ade: value3, cde: value4, fgi: value5}`

I want to write a function `sortByinput(input)` that takes input as an argument and sort the given dictionary in such a way that the keys that include input should be sorted at top in alphabetical order and the keys then the rest of all below it. So for example:

`sortByInput("a")` for the object `{abc: value1, ab: value2, ade: value3, cde: value4, fgi: value5}` should return:
`{ab: value2, abc: value1, ade: value3, cde: value4, fgi: value5}`

and
`sortByInput("c")` for the object

```
{abc: value1, ab: value2, ade: value3, cde: value4, fgi: value5}
```

should return:

```
{cde: value4, ab: value2, abc: value1, ade: value3, fgi: value5}
```

Comment: order of keys in a js object is never guaranteed

Comment: hmm... I see... :-/

Comment: object properties cannot be arranged

Comment: Ok so chuck arrangement, is it possible to just bring the searched parameter element to top?

Comment: you can use Object.keys(yourObject) to extract all the keys into an array, you can then rearrange the array of keys

Comment: I see... hmm thanks!

Comment: you have to convert it into an array if you want it to arrange its order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.keys`, you can get all keys in the input object and sort that keys using `Array.prototype.sort`.

And based on the sorted keys, you can get the new sorted object by assigning the sorted key value to the new object inside `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
function sortByInput(input, startKey) {
  const sortedKeys = Object.keys(input).sort((a, b) => {
    const aCheck = a.startsWith(startKey); // Check if a starts with the startKey
    const bCheck = b.startsWith(startKey); // Check if b starts with the startKey
    
    if (aCheck && !bCheck) { // If a starts with startKey but not b
      return -1; // Keep the position
    }
    if (!aCheck && bCheck) { // If b starts with startKey but not b
      return 1; // Exchange the position
    }
    
    return a > b;
  });
  
  const output = {};
  sortedKeys.map((key) => output[key] = input[key]);
  return output;
}

const input = {
  abc: 'value1',
  ab: 'value2',
  ade: 'value3',
  cde: 'value4',
  fgi: 'value5'
};

console.log(sortByInput(input, 'a'));
console.log(sortByInput(input, 'c'));
```